# How to draw Boxplot with only stats variables in SPSS

Tags: spss

I am trying to draw a boxplot using only Q1, Q3, Max, Min and Mean values as I don't have the whole data, can anyone help me with that?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, it is not a box plot anymore (the whiskers in a traditional box plot are not set to the minimum and maximum values), so you want to be very clear in the notes about what this chart is showing. But given that information one can build a similar looking chart by superimposing the various elements. Example below:

```
DATA LIST FREE / Id Min Q1 Mean Q3 Max.
BEGIN DATA
1 1 2 3 4 5
2 1 3 5 7 9
3 1 5 8 8 10
END DATA.
FORMATS All (F2.0).
GGRAPH
  /GRAPHDATASET NAME="graphdataset" VARIABLES=Id Min Q1 Mean Q3 Max
  /GRAPHSPEC SOURCE=INLINE.
BEGIN GPL
  SOURCE: s=userSource(id("graphdataset"))
  DATA: Id=col(source(s), name("Id"), unit.category())
  DATA: Min=col(source(s), name("Min"))
  DATA: Q1=col(source(s), name("Q1"))
  DATA: Mean=col(source(s), name("Mean"))
  DATA: Q3=col(source(s), name("Q3"))
  DATA: Max=col(source(s), name("Max"))
  GUIDE: axis(dim(1), label("Id"))
  GUIDE: axis(dim(2), label("Variable"))
  ELEMENT: edge(position(Id*(Min+Max)))
  ELEMENT: bar(position(region.spread.range(Id*(Q1+Q3))))
  ELEMENT: point(position(Id*Mean), color.interior(color.grey), size(size."12"))
END GPL.
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I need to draw a boxplot where the lower and the upper fence can be drawn using IQR and the max and min values are considered outliers, 
Min = 95, Q1= 97, M = 100, Q3 = 105.5 and Max = 140. Then we can calculate the upper and lower fences, The upper fence will be:118.75
and The lower fence will be 84.75 so the min and max values will be considered as outliers ... could you please help me with that.

Comment: Above shows all the necessary steps, just replace `ELEMENT: edge(position(Id*(Min+Max)))` with whatever fence calculation you want. You need to be more specific for me to bother to write more code - for instance do you want the fence to go beyond the min and max values? That is kind of weird. If you have positive data do you want the fence to be truncated at zero? You can do some calculations directly within the GPL call using the `TRANS` statement - but those cases I mentioned would be easier just to calculate in SPSS first and then pass to the graph.